# RestTemplate and HTTP Basic but with hidden credentials

Tags: java, spring-security

I'd like to make an HTTP request to one of the secured endpoints in my rest controller.

I'd like it to do that with `RestTemplate` and use basic auth to authenticate. However, I don't want to explicitly state username and password in the code. Thus:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setBasicAuth("admin", "admin");
```

is something I want to avoid.

Can someone please help me do so?

**EDIT**: I realize I need to give more context, the above is way too little.

I'm making a full-stack web app. I use Spring Boot for backend and Vaadin for frontend. I do have 2 endpoints and both of them retrieve a list of `Entity` objects.

1. `/api/entity` - retrives a part of `Entity` objects from database.
2. `/api/admin/entity` - retrives all `Entity` objects.

There's `EntityView` class which is essentially a Vaadin class responsible for graphical displaying of the `Entity` data. Now, this view is restricted to **AUTHENTICATED** users only.

So, a user logs into the application. Then, user accesses the page (through `/entity` endpoint). Then, on the page there's a grid which is supposed to have `Entity` objects in it.

So, I've written an `updateList` method which is supposed to fill the grid with data.

```
private void updateList(UserDetails loggedUser) {
    if(loggedUser.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(Roles.ADMIN))) {
        ResponseEntity<List<Entity>> response = restTemplate.
               exchange("/api/admin/entity", HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Entity>>() {});
        this.grid.setItems(response.getBody());
    } else {
        ResponseEntity<List<Entity>> response = restTemplate.
               exchange("/api/entity", HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Entity>>() {}); 
        this.grid.setItems(response.getBody());
    }
```

How do I provide `RestTemplate` with the `loggedUser` credentials?

**EDIT 2:** I'm looking forward to any feedback on the actual practice of connecting the backend with frontend this way. For example, in Vaadin's official tutorials, they used services to connect with backend. I use (well, I'm trying to) controller to do so as I intuitively think that's better?

I'm, however, looking for discussion on this subject as well. Maybe I should use `EntityService` instead of `EntityController`? Why so?

Comment: you can encrypt your username and password?

Comment: `headers.setBasicAuth(loggedUser.getUsername(), loggedUser.getPassword());` <-- hashed password.


`HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);` <-- creating Http entity with above header


`var response = restTemplate.exchange("/api/admin/entity", HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);` <-- and making an HTTP request.
Providing hashed password as password to Authorization Basic header does not work

Comment: `However, I don't want to explicitly state username and password in the code` so what do you actually want to do?

Comment: @Toerktumlare
I'm using Vaadin for frontend and I'd like some of my views (pages) to have slighlty different content depending on the currently logged-in user.

For example, I've got a grid which contains some entities. When noone is logged-in, then I'd like to fetch these entities from `/api/entity`. However, if it's admin visiting this view, then the entities should be acquired from `/api/admin/entity` endpoint.

Obviously `/api/admin/entity` is secured, thus I need to provide admin's credentials. I don't want to do it explicitly, but I can - for example - provide it with `UserDetails`.

Comment: please update your question with your actual intent istead of writing it in the comments

Comment: `However, if it's admin visiting this view,` if an admin is visiting he must first login, so he should then provide his username and password.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Yes, admin provides credentials what results in successful authentication. But in view class, `RestTemplate` (I've tried also `WebClient`) needs to have admin credentials passed: it does not detect them automatically. Here's where I'm stuck :/

Comment: @Toerktumlare I've updated main post. Thanks! I'd be grateful, if you had taken a look :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to get the logged-in user and then perform a REST API call with the user's credentials. You can use the security context to obtain the credentials of the logged-in user `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials()`. The credentials are set by the `AuthenticationManager` that you have configured.

Comment: @spyrospal Yes, you got it, but the `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials()` returned `null`. Correct me if I'm wrong, but after the authentication Spring erases the credentials. As you suggested, I've configured `AuthenticationManager` and made it *not* erase the credentials through `authenticationManagerBuilder.eraseCredentials(false);`. Now I can use RestTemplate, but I feel like this approach - with credentials not erased - is bad practice. Did you have another concept in mind in terms of `AuthenticationManager` config?

Comment: You can set the username and password on the `UserDetails` object by configuring the `AuthenticationManager` to populate those values so it is available there instead of on the `Credentials` object. I am not sure that this is a good practice tho

Comment: Yeah, right that's also possible. But as you said, I don't think this is a good practice...

Until I find the solution to the question's problem, I'll use services to communicate with back-end, not controllers.